# Подсчитать Количество Символов В Строке. Никак не могу решить

Tags: c#, строки, циклы, словари, символы

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp36
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var str = "aabacibgeeafe";
            var dictChars = new Dictionary<char, int>();

            for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
            {
                if (str[i] == 'a')
                i++;
            }

            foreach (var (key, value) in dictChars)
                Console.WriteLine($"{key} => {value}");
        }
   }
}               //нужно вывести в консоль следующее:
            // a => 4
            // b => 2
            // c => 1
            // i => 1
            // g => 1
            // e => 3
            // f => 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Классическая задача на подсчет повторяющихся символов, решается с помощью словаря и здесь не один раз уже встречалась. Но с ходу дубликат не нашел, поэтому набросал быстрый пример кода.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string text = "aabacibgeeafe";
    Dictionary<char, int> map = new();
    foreach (char c in text)
    {
        if (map.ContainsKey(c))
            map[c]++;
        else
            map[c] = 1;
    }

    foreach (var pair in map)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{pair.Key} = {pair.Value}");
    }
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
a = 4
b = 2
c = 1
i = 1
g = 1
e = 3
f = 1
```